# Class level object initialization throws NullPointer Exception

Tags: java

I have two public classes class A and class B in two different packages.

So when I try to initialize class B inside class A, it throws a null pointer exception. Something like :

```
public class A {
  class B = new class B();
}
```

Infact I have to initialize it inside a method to use it. Example :

```
public class A {
 public void method(){
  class B = new class B();
 }
}
```

I know I am missing something here, but need an urgent help on this

Comment: Check if you can do the same with two classes in the same package.

Comment: Also... what's the exact text of the exception?

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**: You *should* have a constructor

Like:

```
public class A {
  public B theB;
  public A(){
    this.theB = new B();
  }
}
```

But you can use an implicit one like this:

```
public class A {
  public B theB = new B();
}
```

You hadn't named your class member variable, hence you were getting strange errors. In fact... I'm surprised it compiled.

Comment: nope, not working

Comment: Well, there's no way this will ever work: `class B = new class B();` because you are not assigning it to a variable. Are you perhaps leaving out too many details and obscuring the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You are obscuring/simplifying too much for me to be sure, but in order to initialize a class don't forget it still is a variable.

```
public class A {
  public classB nameForB = new classB();

  //class A methods
}
```

Or if you want B to only be initialized upon the initialization of A (which is safer imo)

```
public class A {
  public classB nameForB;

  public A(){
    nameForB  = new classB();
  }

  //class A methods
```

Comment: Given that `nameForB` is an instance variable in both cases, both of your approaches would not initialize/instantiate that variable until an instance of `A` is created. There should be no difference. Like you said though, OP has changed their example code too much for us to be able to know what the actual problem is.